# Why decimal.Parse(10 10) is valid?

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

Why `decimal.Parse(10 10)` is valid?
I need to get exception in such case.
Please advise me something.

```
decimal c;
try
{
   c = decimal.Parse("10 10");
   Console.Write(c);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: You should specify CultureInfo.

Comment: Because parsing stops at whitespace.

Comment: This code throws an exception when I run it ...

Comment: presumably the output is `1010`, `10` or `10.1`, which?

Comment: also notice your catch block is useless like that, give name to the exception and at minimum do a Debug.Write so you can catch it while debugging...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This throws an exception when I run it - which leads me to suspect that it's culture-sensitive.

My guess is that you're in a culture which uses space as a "thousands" separator. For example, if I try to parse "10,10" that works because comma is the thousands separator in my default culture.

To prevent this, use

```
decimal value = decimal.Parse(text, NumberStyles.None);
```

... or some other appropriate combination of [`NumberStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) which excludes `AllowThousands`.

Answer (score 8):

From MSDN: "Parameter s is interpreted using the NumberStyles.Number style. This means that **white space and thousands separators are allowed** but currency symbols are not. To explicitly define the elements (such as currency symbols, thousands separators, and white space) that can be present in s, **use either the Decimal.Parse(String, NumberStyles) or the Decimal.Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider) method**."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z.aspx

**edit:** To further clarify, you need to either

1. explicitly set the culture of your application to one which does NOT allow whitespace in numbers, or
2. explicitly provide a NumberStyles parameter which specifies that whitespace is NOT allowed

**edit 2:** Jon Skeet's answer is correct. For example, the following does NOT throw an exception, because whitespace is used as thousands separators in sv-SE:

```
Decimal.Parse(" 10 10 ", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE").NumberFormat)
```

The following, however, DOES throw an exception:

```
Decimal.Parse(" 10 10 ", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat)
```

Comment: I would have thought that he is calling the single-parameter version Decimal.Parse(String) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z.aspx in which no intermediate whitespace seems to be allowed, according to the description in MSDN (It says "[ws][sign][digits,]digits[.fractional-digits][ws]")

Comment: -1 because a) quotes from MSDN without explanation are usually not good quality answers, b) the example code **throws an exception**, c) this passage means that `"   10  "` parses, **not** that `"10 10"` parses.

Comment: @Daniel: Oops. Wrong URL. The single-parameter method allows whitespace.

Comment: @CPX It allows _leading_ and _trailing_ whitespace, but apparently not whitespace between digits...

Comment: @Jon: a) Well, I think the question got the answer it deserved. It takes about 10 seconds to get to the appropriate documentation for the method. b,c) Test the code for yourself. Decimal.Parse("10 10") runs just fine.

Comment: @Daniel: Try it for yourself. Decimal.Parse(" 10 10 ") returns 1010.

Comment: @Daniel & Jon: As Jon Skeet suggests below, it is probably culture-sensitive.

Comment: @CPX: a) my opinion of the answer in this case has nothing to do with the question it answers, b) I did test on ideone, c) if you take a longer read of the page you linked to yourself, you will see that the allowed pattern is `[ws][sign][digits,]digits[.fractional-digits][ws]` *which does not allow whitespace in the middle*. Finally, Skeet's answer, while a bit speculative, does offer some value.

Comment: @Jon: Fair enough. Would you care to revise your opinion based upon the edits I have made to the answer?

Comment: @CPX: Sure, downvote removed (although I think the answer can still be improved).

Comment: @CPX I was not questioning the tests you made, I just said that the explanation given in MSDN for Decimal.Parse(string) did not seem to leave room for inter-digit whitespace.

Comment: @Daniel: Well I guess it depends on your definition of whitespace ;) If whitespace is used as a number separator, is it still called whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran this code on Visual Studio 2010/C# 4.0, and got a FormatException, as expected. What regional settings is your computer configured to use? Is it possible that you have " " (space) as a thousands separator or decimal separator?